# I thought I was a boat owner with a loan, only to find out I was used as a cosigner. What are my rights?

Tags: loans, fraud, co-sign, divorce

I thought I purchased a boat. I signed the paperwork as a borrower, only to find out I was used as a cosigner. He filed for divorce and took off with the boat. He is always 2 payments behind. What are my rights?

Comment: This is more of a legal question. Your best bet would be to consult a lawyer.

Comment: Which country are you in?

Comment: Probably nothing you can do. Lesson: _Read_ what you sign.

Answer (score 7):

If he bought the boat while you were married it is likely considered community property regardless of whether your name is on the title or loan. Tell your divorce attorney about it and the judge will have to make a call on equitable distribution of assets.